# Plotting Time-Series Data with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, time

I would like to receive my data over time graphically, but I want to start with "Jan 2015" and end with "Feb 2018".

I tried the following:

```
ggplot(PerMonth, aes(x = as.Date(Date), y = Amount)) + 
  geom_line(color=  "#099FDB", size = 1) +
  theme_minimal()+ scale_x_date(date_labels="%b-%y",breaks = "6 month") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Total Number of Reviews",limits=c(0,120000),breaks=seq(0,120000,20000))
```

[image: Graph]

My time data has the following structure:
(I used "as.yearmon(df$time)")

Jan 2015

Feb 2015

...

Feb 2018

Comment: `scale_x_date(date_labels="%b-%y",breaks = "6 month", xlim = zoo::as.yearmon(c("jan15", 'feb18'), "%b%y"))`?